# Can't figure out how to work with {this.props.etc} especially with map in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var Order = React.createClass({
  loadOrderFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data:data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },  
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.loadOrderFromServer();
      setInterval(this.loadOrderFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="orderInformationTable">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="200">General Info</th>
              <th> </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>    
           <OrderInformationTable order={this.state.data.order} />
         </tbody>
       </table>  
       </div>
      );  
     }
   });



var OrderInformationTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

 var orderInfo = this.props.order.map(function (info) {
   return ( 
     <tr>
       <td>{info.attribute}</td>  
       <td>{info.value}</td> 
     </tr>
   )
 });

  return (
    <div className="orderInfoTableContents">
      {orderInfo}
    </div>  
  );
 }
});

    React.render(
    <Order url="api_url" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('order')
    );
```

// The data from the api is formatted like this

```
{
"order":[
  {"attribute":"id","value":2066},
  {"attribute":"name","value":"John D."},
  {"attribute":"location","value":"USA"},
],
"pieces":[
{"id":2,"type":"Diamond Ring","status":null,
  "items":[
  {"id":3,"type":"setting","style":"solitaire"},   
  {"id":2,"type":"setting","style":"style 3"}  ],
"tasks":[
  {"number":1,"task":"order diamond","description":"for diamond 43","status":"in progress"}  ]
} <-- end of a single "piece"
] <-- end of array of "pieces"
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
TypeError: this.props.order is undefined

I succeeded in doing this exact thing using static dummy data where everything was props, but now that I'm using state, it doesn't work, and I can't figure out the error.

Also, I can access the this.props.order in the OrderInformationTable to display it, but I can't do anything with it.  I'm therefore not sure I understand what the nature of this object is. And I'm sure the data from the api and the this.state.data are correct. Thank you in advance to anyone who can shed light on this!

Comment: When `OrderInformationTable` is rendered, the ajax request might not be finished so no data is sent to the child component and `this.props.order`` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, `OrderInformationTable` is rendered before the *ajax request* is finished and this results in no props beeing passed to this child component in the beggining.

One way to probably solve this is :

```
var OrderInformationTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  var orderInfo;
  if (this.props.order) {

    orderInfo = this.props.order.map(function (info) {
      return ( 
        <tr>
          <td>{info.attribute}</td>  
          <td>{info.value}</td> 
        </tr>
      )
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="orderInfoTableContents">
      {orderInfo}
    </div>  
  );
 }
});
```

This is how it works:
- React Components have [lifecycles](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods). What you are doing with your code is waiting for the component to be mounted and then you start your ajax request which is (as the name suggests) asynchronous.
So what happens?
Well, you component is mounted and at this point there is no `data` in your `state` so you send nothing to the `OrderInformationTable` so when you try to `map` through `this.props.order` and error occurs because AT THIS POINT there is no `this.props.order`. If you avoid this error, by either checking if `this.props.order` is defined or any other way to avoid this you will be safe because after your *ajax request* finishes, you will get your `data`, your state will be passed to `OrderInformationTable` through `props` and your component will update and render your new content.

Hope this clears you out.

Comment: Thanks to you both! I'll try this tomorrow and see if that is the problem. It seems like this might be a standard thing- is there an elegant way to account for this issue? Thanks

Comment: whoops, i mean just thanks to you jsam.  Also, thinking about it, this is not intuitive to me because if I erase var orderInfo and have the render function return {this.props.order}, all of my information prints to the screen.  In addition, if I try to access the array, like this.props.order[0], it doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thats normal. When you change your render to just {this.props.order} react is smart enought to render a blank component. But when you are trying to access this.props.order[0] and this.props.order is not defined, thats an error.

Comment: I updated my answer to your question. Go check it out and see if it helps you better this time.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much- this was such a headache.  I am about to implement your solution, and I'll let you know that it works.